# How does \usepackage work?

Tags: packages

I have a style file which includes another `.sty` file
with `\usepackage`. Everything works fine. Since this is a 
small file written by myself I decided to insert it verbatim
at the same place were I use `\usepackage` in the surrounding
file. But this results in errors. This gives raise to
the general question in the title. More specific:

What do I have to do to make such an inclusion work?

Comment: In general we need a MWE to know what are the problems. A possibility in your case is that in your `.sty` file you have commands defined with `@` in their names.  You can try to surround the content of the `.sty` file with `\makeatletter` (before it) and `\makeatother` after it.

Comment: No, there are no such commands. The first error message is:  Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.

Comment: Then please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: `\usepackage` just arranges that `@` is a letter, checks the package name against any `\ProvidesPackage` in the included file and then does `\input`. You need to put the _exact_ error message (and an example document) into your question but the error you described in a comment is not due to the things you describe in the question so there is an error in code you have not described.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This answers my question. Please write an answer and I will accept it. My question was not what is my error (which is certainly purely accidental and therefore I did not include a MWE). I want to know a general method which works in _all_ such cases. Thus, if a conflict with '@' is excluded there must be a conflict with the check against \ProvidesPackage, right? So what does this check do?

Comment: The providespackge error is self explanatory: if you \usepackage{aaa} and the file says it \ProvidePackage{bbb} then you get an error that aaa is not equal to bbb

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`\usepackage` just arranges that `@` is a letter, checks the package name against any `\ProvidesPackage` in the included file and then does `\input`.